# Sign-magnitude and two's compliment

Tags: binary, theory, twos-complement

I am doing an assignment and am stuck can anyone please help?

> A new computer has been acquired by management of CIPOL a research lab sited around Teshie to help in the analysis of samples of blood taken from suspected cases of COVID-19. Upon testing the computer, it was realized by technicians that it can only process data fed into it in the form of sign magnitude. However, all the equipment in CIPOL work in the 2’complement environment. There is currently no interface to link the old systems and new computer. As the technical team leader, you have been summoned to brief management on the problem on hand. You are to:
>
> Critically explain the challenge faced by your team in connection with the new and old computers and propose a solution to it.

This is my answer to the question I am not sure if I am right:

> Sign-magnitude is a way the computer stores negative numbers. There are two other ways which is 1’s compliment and 2’s complement. The new computer that represents data in sign-magnitute will work perfectly the old systems.

Comment: Not right. Google sign-magnitude representation and think about it a bit. How would you convert it to 2s complement?

Comment: @Eraklon is correct and you shouldn't have that much trouble answering the question with a quick google search; there are also many YouTube videos about it. Right off the bat, you will find [this neat article](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/~tomf/notes/cps104/twoscomp.html) by Thomas Finley from Cornell University.

Comment: @Abubakari Sadic, what is my answer missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The new computer will *not* work seamlessly with the old system.**

## 1. Signed and Magnitude Binary Representation

Sign magnitude uses the first bit to denote the sign of the number. So, for example:

- `000` is 0.
- `001` is 1, the first `0` being the `+` sign.
- `101` is -1, the first `1` being the `-` sign.

## 2. Two-Complement Binary Representation

This representation flips the bits of the number and adds one to represent the negative counterpart:

- `000` is still 0.
- `001` is also still 1.
- `111` is -1. Basically flip every bit of `001` and add 1 to it.

## 3. The Solution

I suppose you're gonna want to convert **from signed to two-complement** representation, since everything else in the lab already uses the signed representation.

- Positive Numbers

  - No need to change.
- Negative Numbers

  - I.e., if the first bit is `1`:

    1. Replace the first bit with `0`.
    2. Flip all of the bits (that's a simple `NOT` logical operator).
    3. Add 1 to the new number.
  - An example with `1011` or -3 in the signed representation with 4 bits:

    1. Replace the first bit with `0` → `0011`
    2. Flip all of the bits → `1100`
    3. Add 1 to the new number → `1101`

## 4. Further Reading

There are plenty of tutorials, videos and articles on this topic. If you wanna learn more:

- [Wikipedia: Signed Number Representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations)
- [Two's Complement, by Thomas Finley from Cornell University](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/~tomf/notes/cps104/twoscomp.html)
- [Wikipedia: Two's Complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement#Converting_to_two's_complement_representation)